# Backup internet connection for specific process

Tags: linux, networking

I'd like to add a secondary backup internet connection to my Linux server.  I plan to use a USB LTE modem for this purpose.

Because this cellular connection will be metered, I want to limit the amount of data that can be consumed to the absolute minimum necessary.

I have a custom server application that I can make any changes to.  It has a few tasks where uninterrupted connectivity is critical, and other tasks where downtime doesn't really matter.

I'm imagining something like this:

- Server needs to make an external HTTP API request.  The first attempt is made over the system's default route (ie eth0, the primary internet connection).
- If the request fails or times out, retry the request over the LTE interface.

Only traffic that my server process explicitly wants to send over LTE should be sent over LTE.  No other traffic from any part of the system should go over LTE.

- Specifically, I'll use node's [`localAddress`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_options_connectlistener) socket option to specify that the request should be made over LTE.
- How do I ensure that other traffic does not end up routing over the LTE interface (even if eth0 is down)?
- What about DNS resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up achieving this by configuring an [alternate route table](http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-tables.html) and a [routing policy rule](http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-rpdb.html) for the source address of the backup interface.

The USB LTE modem I have presents as a NDIS device, so it simply shows up as `eth1` with an IP of 192.168.0.190 and it does NAT routing internally.  I've configured `eth1` with a static IP and manually configured routes.

1. The default configuration uses DHCP, so bring down the interface and ensure that any automatically added routes are deleted.
2. Add a static IP configuration for the interface and bring it up.
3. Add entries to an alternate routing table (I've chosen `1`) for the subnet and default gateway.

   ```
   # ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1 src 192.168.1.190 table 1
   # ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 table 1
   ```
4. Set routing policy rules so that apps which explicitly use 192.168.1.190 as their source address will use routing table 1 instead of the default.

   ```
   # ip rule add from 192.168.0.190/32 table 1
   # ip rule add to 192.168.0.190/32 table 1
   ```

At this point, you should be able to test your connectivity.

```sh
$ curl https://wtfismyip.com/text
1.2.3.4  # primary ISP external IP
$ curl --interface 192.168.0.190 https://wtfismyip.com/text
5.6.7.8  # backup LTE external IP
```

If all looks good, make the configuration permanent.  I added to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.0.190
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        post-up ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1 src 192.168.0.190 table 1
        post-up ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 table 1
        post-up ip rule add from 192.168.0.190/32 table 1
        post-up ip rule add to 192.168.0.190/32 table 1
```

Now only apps that explicitly bind to 192.168.0.190 when making outgoing connections will be routed over the backup connection.  All other traffic gets routed over `eth0` (or whatever is configured in the `main` [default] routing table).

It is *possible* that you have something that enumerates all available IPs and attempts to send traffic from them, which could result in unexpected traffic over the backup connection, but that's unlikely.  I've not observed any such traffic.

Note that this does not address DNS resolution.  In a situation where the primary connection is offline, you may get lucky and have get a lookup from cache, but that's not good to rely on.  I wouldn't configure the systemwide resolver to send requests over the LTE interface either.  Instead, your app could manually handle DNS resolution when making backup requests.

---

With node, making HTTP requests (or any TCP connection) from a specific source address is easy.  Simply specify the [`localAddress` option](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_options_connectlistener), eg:

```js
https.get('https://wtfismyip.com/text', { localAddress: '192.168.0.190' }, …);
```

Solving the DNS lookup is slightly trickier.  A `lookup` option is also available, which allows you to override the default DNS resolution process.  You can use a custom [`dns.Resolver`](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_class_dns_resolver) to make lookups.  Unfortunately, node did not have a way to specify the source address for DNS lookups, [so I added it](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/34824).  With that in place, you can put the pieces together:

```js
const resolver = new dns.Resolver();
resolver.setServers(['8.8.8.8']);
resolver.setLocalAddress('192.168.0.190'); // requires node > v15.0.0

https.get('https://wtfismyip.com/text', {
  localAddress: '192.168.0.190',
  lookup: function(hostname, opts, cb) {
    resolver.resolve(hostname, function(err, records) {
      if (err) cb(err);
      else if (!records[0]) cb(new Error('Missing DNS record'));
      else cb(null, records[0], 4);
    });
  }
}, function(res) { … });
```